# Magento 2 Theme - grunt watch with overridden {module}.scss

Tags: frontend, grunt

we are working on a magento 2 theme and followed the official guidelines regarding structure, naming and grunt. there is a correct grunt config and everything works fine with local styles (eg. local-l.less) - which are referenced in themes.js as "files: [...".

but, what about other stuff like a _navigation.scss, that lives in our themes web/css/source? when i run "grunt refresh", changes to that file are successfully deployed and delivered. its not very handy, to use "grunt refresh" everytime, when a line is changed in such a file. is there any possbility to integrate that with grunt watch?

regards,
dominik

Answer (score 0):

ok - the solution is, to add styles-m and styles-l to grunt config, even if that two files are not present in your theme:

'css/styles-m',
'css/styles-l',